# How to Change Height of Custom Dialog's Title Bar in Android

Tags: android, titlebar

In my android app I have a custom dialog box. I want to set the height of dialog's Title bar. My style is as follows:

```
<resources>
    <style name="customDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
        <item name="android:background">#04a9ee</item>
        <item name="android:height">5dp</item> 
     </style> 
</resources>
```

But there is no effect of "height" attribute on title bar. So, how can the height of custom dialog's title bar can be changed ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeh I just check, you want to use `"android:layout_height"` other heights you can use also like: `"android:minHeight"`

Comment: I have tried both "android:layout_height" and "android:minHeight" but there is no change in the size of title bar. Will these attributes have an effect on Dialog Box or its title bar ?. In my case nothing happens

Comment: You cannot change the height of the title bar in a dialog natively, you will have to create your own view and set the view of the dialog to be your custom view.  This can be done like here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

Your theme:

```
  <resources>
       <style name="MyDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
           .......

       </style>

  </resources>
```

Your Custom Dialog Class:

```
  public class CustomDialog extends Dialog
  {
       public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
           super(context, theme);
       }


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          ........... 

          Resources res = getContext().getResources();
          int titleId = res.getIdentifier("title", "id", "android");
          View title = findViewById(titleId);
          if (title != null) {
              title.getLayoutParams().height = 5; // your height
          }
       }
  }
```

Create dialog and show in your code:

```
   CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
   customDialog.show();
```